Quotient of GL(N) by row permutations
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the quotient space of $GL(n)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ under the action of the permutation group $S^n$ acting as follows
$$
X\sim Y \Leftrightarrow (\exists \pi \in S^n)\, X_i = Y_{\pi(i)} \forall i=1,\dots,n
$$
where $X_i$ denotes the $i^\text{th}$ row of $X$ and $Y_j$ the $j^\text{th}$ row of $Y$.
If we equip $GL(n)$ with the Euclidean topology, then is $\mathcal{M}$ an orbifold and what is its dimension?

Are you working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

@SamHopkins I'm working over $\mathbb{R}$.

Okay, probably you should include that information in the post. Also I feel like "what is $\mathcal{M}$ homeomorphic to" is kind of a vague question: a trivial answer is that it's homeomorphic to itself!; and I expect its homeomorphism type might not have any particularly simple description. Maybe a more precise/interesting question is if the quotient remains homotopy equivalent to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Thank you  and +1for your post

@SamHopkins may be a possible mqnifold structure or orbifold structure or group(oid) structure of the quotient space can be discussed here

@SamHopkins Fair point, updated :)

I'm not an expert, but I think taking the quotient by a finite group action should not change the dimension, so it should still be $n^2$.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn I'm also no an expert in this area, but why is this the case?

I think the definition of orbifold as for instance on Wikipedia makes it immediate that your example is an orbifold of dimension $n^2$, with a single chart $V = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf R)$ with finite group $\Gamma = S_n$ acting faithfully (only $1 \in S_n$ acts as the identity).

The quotient is a manifold... the action on $GL(n)$ is free. You only get fixed points when it's possible for two rows to coincide, in which case you're looking at non-invertible matrices.

@mme So, more generally, we have a manifold if we consider the set of $n\times m$ matrices with $n\le m$ with full row-rank?
